# What is POI and what does it mean?

Tags: c++, templates, scope

What is POI? I have seen this term being used several times in context of C++ Templates. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POI means Point Of Instantiation.

From C++ Templates : The Complete Guide

> 10.3.2 Points of Instantiation
>
> A point of instantiation (POI) is created when a code construct refers to a template specialization in such a way that the definition of the corresponding template needs to be instantiated to create that specialization. *The POI is a point in the source where the substituted template could be inserted.*:

Comment: Can you supply links to this doc?

Comment: The book is not available for free. You can buy it [here](http://www.amazon.com/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0201734842)

Answer (score 6):

Point Of Instantiation. It's important with templates largely because the meaning of a symbol inside the template can depend on the meaning attached to that symbol at the point of instantiation.