# Error on save and load data on queue and stack data structures using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am new in using boost serialization library.

I want to save and load data to and from STL structures using text_iarchive and text_oarchive.

On `map`, `list`, `deque`, `set` and `vector` there isn't any problem but on `queue` and `stack` I get following errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'save(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, const std::deque<PKT_UNIT, std::allocator<PKT_UNIT> >&, const unsigned int&)' 
error: no matching function for call to 'load(boost::archive::text_iarchive&, std::deque<PKT_UNIT, std::allocator<PKT_UNIT> >&, const unsigned int&)'
```

I used bellow code for that:

```
mystruct test;
test.initial();
{
    std::ofstream ofs("filename.dat");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
    ar & test;
}
{
    std::ifstream ifs("filename.dat");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(ifs);
    mystruct restored;
    ar & restored;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sehe unfortunately I couldn't run my code on coliru viewer then I post it here. although it is simple to describe.
when I used following order of header I got those two errors that mentioned on text_iarchive and text_oarchive for stack and queue structure :

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/set.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/queue.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/stack.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/deque.hpp>
```

But when I used this order problem solved

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/set.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/deque.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/queue.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/stack.hpp>
```

Answer (score 3):

Stack and queue aren't containers. They are container adaptors.

By design they don't expose *raw* access to the underlying container but the underlying containers **are** serializable standard library containers (`vector<>` and `deque<>`, by default respectively).

Boost serialization employs a trick with a derived class to get access to [the underlying container `::c`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack#Member_objects).

Due to technicalities surrounding the exact point-of-instantiation rules and ordering of templates, it is vital that the serialization code for the underlying containers is *visible* (declared) before the serialization code for the container adaptor.

> In fact, clang has a very apt message here:
>
> `boost/serialization/queue.hpp|40 col 9| error: call to function 'save' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup`
>
> The problem, of course, being triggered by the fact that the `load` and `save` functions cannot be put with the containers in their declaring namespace, because that's the `::std` namespace.

### Fix

In the default cases, this means you need to include the serialization for `deque` before `stack` or `queue`:

```
#include <boost/serialization/deque.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/stack.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/queue.hpp>
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2250e2090c0f9fa2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/deque.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/stack.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/queue.hpp>

struct mystruct {
    std::stack<int> _s;
    std::queue<int> _q;

    void foo() {
        _s.push(1); _s.push(2); _s.push(3);
        _q.push(1); _q.push(2); _q.push(3);
    }

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned /*version*/) { ar & _s & _q; }
};

#include <fstream>

int main() {
    {
        mystruct test;

        std::ofstream ofs("filename.dat");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << test;
    }
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("filename.dat");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        mystruct restored;
        ia >> restored;
    }
}
```

The `filename.dat` contains

```
 1  22 serialization::archive 15 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

in that live demo

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer  , yesterday I found out something first when I use cout for printing my structure  it works Okey. but when I want to read and write from file this happens, this problem occurs only with use of stack and queue. At second,  I used headers for serialization in main function before, but when I use that headers for my queue and stack class the problem solved. its wired !.. @sehe

Comment: Can you show in code what you mean (just edit the live example, I guess. Perhaps use http://rextester.com if you need MSVC to reproduce the error). I think you're just getting the [POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866215/what-is-poi-and-what-does-it-mean) wrong. Alternatively you're using MSVC and they fail at it (they do fail at [2-phase name lookup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc&))

Comment: Oh, and [welcome to StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I added a answer for you. @sehe

Comment: @samini great! I got it now. My answer missed the whole point (of course I could have known had I checked the documentation, or if your question had included the code :)). I updated/fixed my answer.

Comment: I still have the problem on queue.hpp with Boost 1.80.0 and adding deque.hpp before solved the problem well, thanks.