# C++ boost serialize polymorphism question

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, polymorphism

I use a pointer of base class to serialize an object of derived class. The code below seems works. But I am fuzzy about the executed order. The output info is:
CC serialize start
BB serialize start
AA serialize start
AA serialize end
BB serialize end
CC serialize end
CC serialize start
BB serialize start
AA serialize start
AA serialize end
BB serialize end
CC serialize end
class_aa
class_bb
class_cc
since the serialize function is not virtual, I am wondering why the serialize fuction in class CC will execute at first, and then BB, AA's serialize function.

Thanks

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp> 
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class AA
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    AA(string aa) :aa_name(aa) { }
    AA() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int)
    {
        cout << "AA serialize start" << endl;
        ar& aa_name;
        cout << "AA serialize end" << endl;
    }

    string aa_name;
};
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(AA);

class BB : public AA
{
public:
    void foo() {}
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    BB(string aa, string bb) : AA(aa), bb_name(bb) {}
    BB() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int)
    {
        cout << "BB serialize start" << endl;
        ar& boost::serialization::base_object<AA>(*this);
        ar& bb_name;
        cout << "BB serialize end" << endl;
    }
    string bb_name;
};
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(BB);

class CC : public BB
{
public:
    CC(string aa, string bb, string cc) : BB(aa, bb), cc_name(cc) {}
    CC() {}
    void bar() {} 

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int)
    {
        cout << "CC serialize start" << endl;
        ar& boost::serialization::base_object<BB>(*this);
        ar& cc_name;
        cout << "CC serialize end" << endl;
    }

    string cc_name;
};
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(CC)


int main(int, char const**)
{
    AA* obj = new CC("class_aa", "class_bb", "class_cc");
    ofstream outfile("archive_test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive out_archive(outfile);
    out_archive << obj;
    outfile.close();

    ifstream infile("archive_test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(infile);
    AA* c;
    ia >> c;
    cout << c->aa_name << endl << dynamic_cast<CC*>(c)->bb_name << endl << dynamic_cast<CC*>(c)->cc_name << endl;
    infile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q.** since the serialize function is not virtual, I am wondering why the serialize fuction in class CC will execute at first, and then BB, AA's serialize function.

The reason is that **when serializing through polymorphic references/pointers**¹ the archive will contain the type id of the serialized type, so the library knows what type to deserialize.

You can actually see this in the archive:

> 22 serialization::archive 18 0 0 1 7 **Derived** 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 class_aa
> 8 class_bb 8 class_cc

You have some control over how the type is exported using the [alternative export macros](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export).

Note that in the above example, the hierarchy lacks a virtual destructor and there's memory leaks. The latter may be obvious, but the former might not².

Here's with

- more virtual dtors
- more access control
- more [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override), [move semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible), [`=default` ctors/dtors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/default)
- less leaks
- replaced direct member access with actual virtual member function use

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d18a0df516acae63)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class Base {
  public:
    Base(std::string aa) : aa_name(std::move(aa)) {}
    Base() = default;

    virtual void foo() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int) {
        std::cout << "Base serialize start" << std::endl;
        ar& aa_name;
        std::cout << "Base serialize end" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string aa_name;
  protected:
    void qux() const { std::cout << aa_name << std::endl; }
};

class Middle : public Base {
  public:
    Middle(std::string aa, std::string Middle) : Base(aa), bb_name(std::move(Middle)) {}
    Middle() = default;

    void foo() const override { qux(); std::cout << bb_name << std::endl; }
    virtual void bar() const = 0;

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int) {
        std::cout << "Middle serialize start" << std::endl;
        ar& boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
        ar& bb_name;
        std::cout << "Middle serialize end" << std::endl;
    }
    std::string bb_name;
};

class Derived : public Middle {
  public:
    Derived(std::string aa, std::string bb, std::string cc) : Middle(aa, bb), cc_name(std::move(cc)) {}
    Derived() = default;

    void bar() const override { foo(); std::cout << cc_name << std::endl; }

 private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int) {
        std::cout << "Derived serialize start" << std::endl;
        ar& boost::serialization::base_object<Middle>(*this);
        ar& cc_name;
        std::cout << "Derived serialize end" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string cc_name;
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Middle)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived)

int main() {
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

    {
        std::ofstream outfile("archive_test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive out_archive(outfile);

        Ptr obj = std::make_unique<Derived>("class_aa", "class_bb", "class_cc");
        out_archive << obj;
    }

    {
        std::ifstream infile("archive_test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(infile);
        Ptr obj;
        ia >> obj;

        if (auto cp = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(obj.get()))
            cp->bar();
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Derived serialize start
Middle serialize start
Base serialize start
Base serialize end
Middle serialize end
Derived serialize end
Derived serialize start
Middle serialize start
Base serialize start
Base serialize end
Middle serialize end
Derived serialize end
class_aa
class_bb
class_cc
```

---

¹ references lead to an entirely different subject: [object tracking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking)

² [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

### BONUS

To the comments, some technical analysis:

The macro `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived)` expands to

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <> struct guid_defined<Derived> : boost::mpl::true_ {};
    template <> inline const char* guid<Derived>() { return "Derived"; }
} }

namespace boost { namespace archive { namespace detail { namespace extra_detail {
    template <> struct init_guid<Derived> {
        static guid_initializer<Derived> const& g;
    };
    guid_initializer<Derived> const& init_guid<Derived>::g =
        ::boost::serialization::singleton<
        guid_initializer<Derived>>::get_mutable_instance()
        .export_guid();
} } } }
```

`export_guid()` reads:

```
guid_initializer const & export_guid() const {
    BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(boost::is_polymorphic< T >::value);
    // note: exporting an abstract base class will have no effect
    // and cannot be used to instantitiate serialization code
    // (one might be using this in a DLL to instantiate code)
    //BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(! boost::serialization::is_abstract< T >::value);
    export_guid(boost::serialization::is_abstract< T >());
    return *this;
}

void export_guid(mpl::false_) const {
    // generates the statically-initialized objects whose constructors
    // register the information allowing serialization of T objects
    // through pointers to their base classes.
    instantiate_ptr_serialization((T*)0, 0, adl_tag());
}
```

Note how it clearly documents that it only makes sense for polymorphic classes. `instantiate_ptr_serialization` actually registers the types [with all known archives](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#:%7E:text=BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT%20in%20the%20same%20source%20module%20that%20includes%20any%20of%20the%20archive%20class%20headers%20will%20instantiate%20code%20required%20to%20serialize%20polymorphic%20pointers%20of%20the%20indicated%20type%20to%20the%20all%20those%20archive%20classes.%20If%20no%20archive%20class%20headers%20are%20included,%20then%20no%20code%20will%20be%20instantiated.).

There's a ton of template machinery to get everything to instantiate (and only once) regardless of your code organization (dynamic/shared linkage, separate translation unit or not). But in the end it goes to `register_type`:

```
template<class T>
const basic_pointer_iserializer *
register_type(T * = NULL){
    const basic_pointer_iserializer & bpis =
        boost::serialization::singleton<
            pointer_iserializer<Archive, T>
        >::get_const_instance();
    this->This()->register_basic_serializer(bpis.get_basic_serializer());
    return & bpis;
}
```

Where it registers the `pointer_iserializer`:

```
template<class Archive, class T>
class pointer_iserializer :
    public basic_pointer_iserializer
{
private:
    virtual void * heap_allocation() const {
        detail::heap_allocation<T> h;
        T * t = h.get();
        h.release();
        return t;
    }
    virtual const basic_iserializer & get_basic_serializer() const {
        return boost::serialization::singleton<
            iserializer<Archive, T>
        >::get_const_instance();
    }
    BOOST_DLLEXPORT virtual void load_object_ptr(
        basic_iarchive & ar,
        void * x,
        const unsigned int file_version
    ) const BOOST_USED;
public:
    // this should alway be a singleton so make the constructor protected
    pointer_iserializer();
    ~pointer_iserializer();
};
```

This wraps the actual new/delete in a `heap_allocation`. For brevity I don't include that here, because I have already analyzed that in more detail here: [How does boost::serialization allocate memory when deserializing through a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105624/how-does-boostserialization-allocate-memory-when-deserializing-through-a-point/62107202#62107202)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and point out my code error with a better code example. I am still a little fuzzy. Does the boost serialization library use type id and do dynamic_cast to execute the serialize function when serializing through polymorphic references/pointers?

Comment: @LIANGKe In general I don't think it's healthy to try to understand every single bit of boost libraries. But if you're like me and just want to know, I [added some analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771254/c-boost-serialize-polymorphism-question/62779642#62779642#:~:text=BONUS) so you can find your way.

Comment: Thanks for your detail analysis and advice. I learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation of boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers), it's explained that this mechanism is automatically executed when the class is polymorphic (i.e. at least one virtual function):

> If the base class is polymorphic, an object of the most derived type (derived_one or derived_two in this case) will be serialized. The question of which type of object is to be serialized is (almost) automatically handled by the library.

Comment: Thanks. But I wonder how it realizes. As you can see, serizalize function is not virtual, but the serialize function of derived class will be executed at first.